# Cannot drop foreign key during Laravel's migration refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

When I try to run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` on my tables, it always get stuck on this one:

```
public function down()
{
    if (Schema::hasTable('leads')) {
        Schema::table('leads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('leads_dealer_id_foreign'); //this is the line
            $table->dropIndex('leads_dealer_id_index');
            $table->dropColumn('dealer_id');
            Schema::dropIfExists('leads');
        });
    }
}
```

The error is: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'leads' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `leads` drop foreign key `leads_dealer_id_foreign`)

I've commented the line that produces the error in the snippet above.

1. Why would it complain about the table not existing? Even if the table doesn't exist, I've wrapped everything inside `Schema::hasTable('leads')` so it shouldn't even execute that line.
2. What causes my `leads` table to drop early? I've looked at my other migrations and nowhere I'm dropping that table except on its own migration file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must drop the foreign keys first, then drop the table. In order to do this move `Schema::dropIfExists('leads');` outside the closure:

```
public function down()
{
    if (Schema::hasTable('leads')) {
        Schema::table('leads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('leads_dealer_id_foreign'); //this is the line
            $table->dropIndex('leads_dealer_id_index');
            $table->dropColumn('dealer_id');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('leads');
    }
}
```